# Hover over one div and it effects another

Tags: css, animation, hover

So I want to hover over a Box and have it activate another div with easing effects. You can see below the `.images{}` has a 0s infinite scroll, and then `.box:hover > .images{}` is when I change the 0s to 10s to start the slideshow.

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="slideshow">
     <div class="images"></div>
     <div class="box"></div>   
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
width:100px;
height:100px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background-color: #333;
}

.images {
  background: url('http://jamesebeling.com/testing/jamesebeling/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/buildings.png');
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: slideshow 0s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:    slideshow 0s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
  0%    { left: 0; }
  100%  { left: -200%; }
}
@moz-keyframes slideshow {
  0%    { left: 0; }
  100%  { left: -200%; }
}
/* Hey browser, use your GPU */
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveSlideshow {
    0%   { 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);  
    }    
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);  
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveSlideshow {
    0%   { 
        -moz-transform:    translateX(0); 
    }    
    100% { 
        -moz-transform:    translateX(-200%); 
    }
}

.box:hover > .images {
.images {
  background: url('http://jamesebeling.com/testing/jamesebeling/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/buildings.png');
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: slideshow 10s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:    slideshow 10s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
  0%    { left: 0; }
  100%  { left: -200%; }
}
@moz-keyframes slideshow {
  0%    { left: 0; }
  100%  { left: -200%; }
}
/* Hey browser, use your GPU */
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveSlideshow {
    0%   { 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);  
    }    
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);  
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes moveSlideshow {
    0%   { 
        -moz-transform:    translateX(0); 
    }    
    100% { 
        -moz-transform:    translateX(-200%); 
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no previous sibling selector in CSS - you'll have to use jQuery

Answer (score 1):

If you change your HTML to include the `box` class before the `images` class, you can use the [adjacent selector](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/selector_adjacent.html) to select the `.images` when it's preceded by `.box:hover`:

```
.box:hover + .images { ... }
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EHCVM/).

I also added `z-index: 1` to `.box` so it sits on top of the images element.